# Ionic/Angular alternative to $stateChangeStart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, transition, ionic-framework

I was wondering if there is an alternative to

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function() {});
```

Because I want to get that event on many pages which do different things. If I use the way above, this event is fired for every page I implemented it (even if the page wasn't where I came from or wasn't where I go to)...which is a little overheading.

So what I am looking for is an event which is fired only if the controller is used on the current page.

Answer (score 2):

use $stateChangeStart instead of $routeChangeStart

there are some differences between Angularjs ngRoute and ui-router.

http://www.amasik.com/angularjs-ngroute-vs-ui-router/

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just use the event $routeChangeStart:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

Comment: If I'm right, the event `$routeChangeStart` doesn't exist in ionic, because they are using the angularjs extension angular-ui.router.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Sorry, I am familiar with angular-ui.router, let me try to research some more.